# Windows 8.1 gets Error 720 on connect VPN

Tags: windows-8.1, vpn

I use windows 8.1 64-bit on my machine and recently, without having installed any new application, I get the following error when connecting to VPN: 
Error 720: Unable to establish a connection to the remote computer. 
Might need to change the network settings for this connection.

Tenentei already follow several tutorials but in no've succeeded.

Example configuration that tried to accomplish:
http://en.remontka.pro/error-720-windows-8-and-8-1-solved/

Thankyou

Comment: Other computers with windows 8.1 can not find the same problem accessing VPN and could not find the difference between the two computers that may be causing the problem

Comment: I tried to use your example configuration and i resolved your issue on my laptop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would like to thank Rose who was willing to help us, but your answer could solve the problem on a computer, but in others there was what was done could not always connect gets error 720. 
After much searching and contact the Microsoft support we can solve.
In Device Manager, on the View menu, select to show hidden devices. 
Made it look for a remote Miniport IP or network monitor that is with warning of problems with the driver icon. In its properties in the details tab check the Key property of the driver. 
Look for this key in Regedit on Local Machine, make a backup of that key and delete it. Restart your windows. 
Reopen your device manager and select the miniport that had deleted the record. Activate the option to update the driver and look for the option driver on the computer manually and then use the option to locate the driver from the list available on the computer on the next screen uncheck show compatible hardware. Then you must select the Microsoft Vendor and the driver WAN Miniport the type that is changing, IP or IPV6 L2TP Network Monitor. 
After upgrading restart the computer.

I know it's a bit laborious but that was the only way that worked on all computers.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I found the Miniport IP and all I did was update the driver then it started working again.

Comment: Are you referring to each device's "Driver key"? You're saying you had success deleting the driver's key from the registry location it exists under?

Comment: Yes, we've found this references on the registry and we remove them. So after try you can upgrade these drivers and restart your Windows.

Answer (score 15):

Since I can't find a complete or clear answer on this issue, and since it's the second time that I use this post to fix my problems, I post my solution:

**why 720?** 720 is the error code for connection attempt fail, because your computer and the remote computer could not agree on PPP control protocol, I don't know exactly why it happens, but I think that is all about registry permission for installers and multiple miniport driver install made by vpn installers that are not properly programmed for win 8.1.

Solution:

1. **check write permissions on registers**

   a. download a Process Monitor
   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us//sysinternals/bb896645.aspx and run it

   b. Use registry as target and set the filters to check witch registers aren't writable for netsh: "Process Name is 'netsh.exe'" and "result is 'ACCESS DENIED'", then get a command prompt with admin permissions and type `netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log`

   c. for each registry key logged by the process monitor as not accessible, go to registers using regedit anche change these permissions to "complete access"

   d. run the following command `netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log` and repeat step c)
2. **unistall all not-working miniports**

   a. go to device managers (windows+x -> device manager)

   b. for each not-working miniport (the ones with yellow mark): update driver -> show non-compatible driver -> select another driver (eg. generic broadband adapter)

   c. unistall these not working devices

   d. reboot your computer

   e. Repeat steps a) - d) until you will not see any yellow mark on miniports
3. **delete your vpn connection and create a new one.**

that worked for me (2 times, one after my first vpn connection on win 8.1, then when I reinstalled a cisco client and tried to use windows vpn again)

references:

http://en.remontka.pro/error-720-windows-8-and-8-1-solved/

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-8-and-8-1/SOLVED-WAN-Miniport-2-yellow-exclamation-mark-in-Device-Manager/td-p/1051981

Comment: Solution #2 worked for me on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Solution #3 worked for me on Windows 10

Comment: Great,  solution 2 worked for me on 8.1

Answer (score 2):

This solved my 720 problem. The idea is to change the driver of the faulty WAN to another network adaptar driver, and then we are able to uninstall the WAN device and then reboot the system.

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-8-and-8-1/SOLVED-WAN-Miniport-2-yellow-exclamation-mark-in-Device-Manager/td-p/1051981

Comment: Worked for me as well. It was vital to *reboot* after uninstalling the drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Microsoft support KBs, this can occur if TCP/IP is damaged or is not bound to your dial-up adapter.You can try reinstalling or resetting TCP/IP as follows:

- **Reset TCP/IP to Original Configuration**- Using the NetShell utility,
  type this command (in CommandLine): `netsh int ip reset [file_name.txt]`,
  [file_name.txt] is the name of the file where the actions taken by
  NetShell are record, for example netsh hint ip reset fixtcpip.txt.
- **Remove and re-install NIC** – Open Controller and select System. Click
  Hardware tab and select devices. Double-click on Network Adapter and
  right-click on the NIC, select Uninstall. Restart the computer and
  the Windows should auto detect the NIC and re-install it.
- **Upgrade the NIC driver** – You may download the latest NIC driver and
  upgrade the driver.

Hope it could help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Most posted solutions would not work.
I ran sfc /scannow and it reported that some errors could not be fixed.
To address that problem I ran the command

Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Ironically, I later found the WAN errors had gone away, the 720 VPN error went away and my VPN worked.

Hard to believe that the WAN errors were corrected by this rather esoteric command, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Your solution is like raising an apartment then rebuilding it from scratch to fix a window handle on 10th floor